# How to define association field name

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create association between my ECT in Sharepoint designer 2010.

First ECT is `Task`, that has field `Assignee`. Second ECT is `User`. I want to tie them by `Assignee` field in Task.

All works fine, but in Task Creation form, i see 0 `User` field instead `Assignee` field. SharePoint Designer renamed that field to relative ECT entity name.

How I can avoid this?

Comment: You might not be able to do this with designer, it may have to be a Visual Studio fix. If you did however find a way around this since the post date please post the answer and mark as complete. (You get a badge if you do this as well!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to create your forms using InfoPath instead of using the built-in SharePoint forms.